# How to display the past 17 trading days (business days) when looking up Stock History in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using the new STOCKHISTORY function in Excel and I'd like to always display the past 17 trading days from the point I indicate. The problem is with long weekends and holidays this alters the amount of business between two dates. I'm not sure if this will be a difficult question because I think the solution is not dependent on the fact that I'm using the STOCKHISTORY function. I have attached a photo with a simple explanation. On the left the formula for STOCKHISTORY is `=STOCKHISTORY(E2,C4-C6,C4,0,1,0,2)`. This displays 17 business days because 22 is the magic number. On the right though if I query July 22nd with 22 day difference I only get 16 days. This is further wrong on many other dates.

I am open to having a separate reference on another sheet that has dates/formulas. I tried this but couldn't figure out a formula to pull down. Photo B displays an example of the correct number of dates that would show 17 trading days. I am also open to displaying more than 17 trading days as in the future I will need to alter the amount of trading days needed (I might need to display 15 days or 20 days).

In my head I feel like the answer has something to do with the NETWORKDAYS function and/or I should make a list of all the trading days in a year and then make a formula taking the current day and taking away a specific day. Or I could be totally wrong and the answer is obvious.
[image: Image 1]
[image]

Comment: I agree that it has to do with NETWORKDAYS. There, the *Holidays* argument adjusts for, well, holidays, and if the list isn't correct the result will be out, too. Please modify your question to show where the NETWORKDAYS enter your STOCKHISTORY function and how the NETWORKDAYS return an unexpected result. I think there is no point in looking into the STOCKHISTORY function before that part has been fully explored but suspect that "22 is the magic number" will end up not holding water.

Comment: I solved the answer below after reading some documentation. I didn't include an unexpected result with STOCKHISTORY when posting my question because I didn't understand that function, therefore, I didn't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out an answer after reading some documentation. There is most likely better answers but it solves the problem enough.

So I created a list of all trading days (business days) as you can see in column O. Then in Column L a list of nearby holidays (Only needed a few exceptions). Then using the formula `=(O35)-(WORKDAY(O36,-17,$L$35:$L$36))` I get the right solution which I verified in my example photo posted earlier. You could theoretically get a different number when doing your own calculations (i.e the answer 24 and 23 are both correct).

[image: Answer]